# STHTTPRequest returning null

Tags: ios, swift, get, sthttprequest

I'm able to load this URL in a safari browser and see the JSON data I need, but this STHTTPRequest is returning null, making me not able to use the JSON, what is going wrong here? I am loading in safari

```
let url = "192.168.101.1:8080/api"
let request = STHTTPRequest.buildGET(URL(string: url), timeout: 15.0)!
```

Comment: Are you loading the URL in Safari on the phone? Have you any error logs? Did you try disabling ATS (App Transport Security)?

Comment: URL loads in safari, no error logs, and enabling arbitrary loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed to add http:// to the beginning of the url, giving `http://192.168.101.1:8080/api/status`

Answer (score 1):

First of all check you are using the latest STHTTPRequest from CocoaPods [STHTTPRequest](https://cocoapods.org/pods/STHTTPRequest).

Then you can simply use the following to initialise and call a request to the url. The result is obtained through body in **completionBlock**

```
guard let request = STHTTPRequest(urlString: url) else {return}
request.timeoutSeconds = TimeInterval(floatLiteral: 15.0)
request.completionBlock = { (headers, body) in
           print(body)
}
request.errorBlock = { (error) in
        // ...
}
request.startAsynchronous()
```

Comment: it's up to date, even with that implementation it returns null

Comment: 1. okay make sure to add http:// prefix to your url. 
2. Also make sure App Transport Security settings is disabled in info.plist or add your domain as an exception.
3. If you are hosting locally with php without the Rewrite rules, do add .php to your endpoint.